# convert listbox items to checked rows in datagridview checkbox column

Tags: c#, listbox

i want to make datagrid (checkecbox column)rows ticked.those rows in datagrid that match studentcode colum already in listbox items .

i have tried the code below.but i don't get the proper result

```
private void btnConvertItemsToCheckedRows_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if(  ListBox1.ListBox.Items.Count>0)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i <ListBox1.ListBox.Items.Count; i++)
    {
      foreach (DataGridViewRow row in GridStudents.DataGridView.Rows)
      {
        if(row.Cells["StudentCode"].Value.ToString().Equals(ListBox1.ListBox.Items[i]))
        {
          GridStudents.DataGridView.Rows[i].DataGridView["ChekboxColumn", i].Value = true;
        }
      }
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead :

```
private void btnConvertItemsToCheckedRows_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if(  ListBox1.ListBox.Items.Count>0)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i <ListBox1.ListBox.Items.Count; i++)
    {
      foreach (DataGridViewRow row in GridStudents.DataGridView.Rows)
      {
        if(row.Cells["StudentCode"].Value.ToString().Equals(ListBox1.ListBox.Items[i]))
        {
          DataGridViewCheckBoxCell chk = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)row.Cells["ChekboxColumn"];
           chk.TrueValue = true;
           chk.Value = chk.TrueValue;
        }
      }
    }
    GridStudents.EndEdit();
  }
}
```

Comment: sorry i am  newbie and get exception error."cannot set 'checkboxcolumn' to be null.Please use DBNull instead.

Comment: Sorry the code has been edited please try again.You can also use row.Cells[CellIndex] instead of row.Cells["ChekboxColumn"]

Comment: Dear Ilia Afzali I corrected the condition to avoid null error this way     "if(row.Cells["ChekboxColumn"].Value != System.DBNull.Value && row.Cells["StudentCode"].Value.ToString().Equals(ListBox1.ListBox.Items[i]))  " but no rows is checked

Comment: Just set a breakpoint on line 12 and check ever condition is true ?